I start receiving an error when I try to run flutter app
I start receiving this error when I try to run my flutter app
and before I received same error but with image that it's from flutter material and coincide with image from another package I got. What I should do? I comment where I had image but I know this is not the right solution

This question is similar to: Error: 'CarouselController' is imported from both Package in Flutter. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I faced the same issue, and I found that the solution is to update the carousel_slider dependency.

In your pubspec.yaml file, update:

carousel_slider: ^4.2.1

To:
carousel_slider: ^5.0.0

Then, run:
flutter pub get


In the file where you use the CarouselController widget, rename it to CarouselSliderController.

This should resolve the problem.
Additionally, starting from the Flutter 3.24.0 release, there is native support for carousels, which might be a more suitable alternative depending on your requirements.

It have conflict import in lib you can try to folk and fix it like this guy did or just use this repo https://github.com/amarjeetpatidar007/flutter_carousel_widget
or just use alternative lib like
infinite_carousel or other carousel lib
hope this will solve your problem
ref : https://stackoverflow.com/a/78690727/10423080
